# Compatible jars for SPRING 3.2.8

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

What are the compatible release version for jars mentioned below for SPRING 3.2.8 release

- spring-data-commons-core
- spring-data-mongodb
- spring-integration-core
- spring-ws-core
- spring-xml

Comment: You should probably go the other way around. If you need spring data what version of spring supports it. etc

Answer (score 0):

You could try these jars:

- spring-data-commons-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-data-mongodb-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-integration-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
- spring-xml-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade to Spring 4.0, then you could have a look at the [`spring-boot-dependencies.pom`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.springframework.boot%22%20AND%20a%3a%22spring-boot-dependencies%22), it contains a set of Dependencies (and there version) that work together.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
```

---

*Btw: I recommend to update to Spring 4.0, to be able to update to 4.1 when necessary. Because:*

> Both (4.0.5 and 3.2.9) of those are designed as a final feature release in the respective line - we will only consider further releases from the 4.0.x and 3.2.x branches in case of serious bugs now. (Spring Blog: [Spring Framework 4.0.5 & 3.2.9 released - next stop: 4.1](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/20/spring-framework-4-0-5-3-2-9-released-next-stop-4-1))